# Develop Windows Manager in Linux with which Library?

Tags: linux, gtk

I want to develop a simple windows manager, but do not know which library to use. Requirements:

Take advantage of the existing high-level libraries to deal with fonts, images. Like GTK+, Clutter, GDK. But keep the design-relevance things out, which libraries should I use? Because I tried to use XCB, which is really painful. And I've heard about Wayland, and if I write it in XCB, it wouldn't be portable to Wayland.

I've read some posts on WM development, typically use XCB and Xlib, I think they are too low-level and I don't want to repeat others work. I want a more user-friendly WM, but keep simple and flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue is not the library to use. It is the complexity of the requirements, as dictated by [ICCCM](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) and [EWMH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints).

A standard compliant window manager is quite complex, because the standards defining it are complex, and because the X11 protocol is complex.

You might fork an existing WM instead.

But any library capable of X11 protocol exchange can fit the bill.

<sup>and I am not sure that Wayland has window managers</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the project in a (low-level) window manager on top of the core X11 libraries, and a high-level part implementing the UI to control the window manager, utilizing whatever toolkit you feel comfortable with.

The difficulty in using a toolkit is that these are not designed to be used from inside a window manager, i.e. the toolkit might expect to be able to send a message to the window manager and receive a reply without returning to "user" code in the middle.

Plus, this allows some more flexibility when using the window manager from different environments -- desktop integrators may choose to rewrite some of the control UI to better match the rest of the system, leaving the core service unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a high-level GUI toolkit to develop a window manager. These GUI toolkits are independent of the window manager and don't have any way to communicate directly with it - only in the ways defined by the standards.